# OpenCart on Windows XP Error

Tags: mysql, opencart

I'm trying to install Open Cart on my virtual machine with, PHP 5.4.7, MySQL 5.5 and Apache 2.2. After A LOT of troubles, I've managed to arrive at the moment of installation script execution, but I receive this problem:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL    server version for the right syntax to use near 'ï»¿/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */' at line 1
```

Honestly I'm stuck. I've tried to execute the code in Workbench and it works, except that in the INSERT INTO queries for test data they've missed default values for NOT NULL columns.

Hints? Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those random characters at the start of the SQL are the UTF Byte Order Mark. Something you used to edit the file decided to emit that at the start. Quickest way to get rid of it would be getting [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), open the file in that, Select "Encoding->Enocde in UTF-8 without BOM", and resave the file, and try again.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem, I though it was a database problem. Just to let you know, I've opened the SQL script with default Windows Notepad.

Comment: Also, the problem with "Field 'image' doesn't have a default value" persists, I've tried to install it on Linux Ubuntu and it worked well.